Calculating $\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}\right)+\arg\left(\frac{z_3-z_4}{z_1-z_4}\right)=\pi$
$$z_1= -1,\quad z_2= i,\quad z_3 = 1\text{ and }z_4 = -i$$ are complex number vertices of a cyclic quadrilateral.
When we apply $$\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}\right)+\arg\left(\frac{z_3-z_4}{z_1-z_4}\right)=\pi$$ to the above cyclic vertices, we get
$$\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}\right)=\arg(-i)=-\frac\pi2$$ and $$\arg\left(\frac{z_3-z_4}{z_1-z_4}\right)= \arg(-i)=-\frac\pi2$$
i.e
$$\arg\left(\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}\right)+\arg\left(\frac{z_3-z_4}{z_1-z_4}\right)=-\pi.$$
Why isn't the formulae hold true?

Please next time improve the formating of your formulas. (I'll do it for you.)

The formula will only be true when $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4$ are in anticlockwise sense , so you need to consider that while applying that here in your case $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4$ are in clockwise sense and that is why the result changes sign. Do you want a proof? or can you figure out for yourself? its quite simple you just need to visualise things, try drawing them and you will observe it
